# Want to save NSDate in plist in GMT timezone

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdate

How can I save an `NSDate` in `GMT` time zone to a `plist`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to remove the empty blockquotes. Next time, please use the `edit` button to add further information instead of commenting the question. Have you already tried to save an `NSDate`? In this case, please do also post your attempt and tell us what went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`NSDate` is directly supported by property lists. For example, you can use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to create an `NSData` from a property list object and write that data object o file.

`NSDate` represents a moment in time without respect to time zone. Time zones are not necessary to represent a moment in time, they are only necessary when converting such moments in time to calendar representations (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, etc.). Any given moment has many different calendar representations and exists in all time zones.